# Fetch Request Result, Core Data & Swift 3

Tags: core-data, entity, nsfetchrequest, swift3, beta

Now that NSFetchResultsController and NSFetchRequest are Generics in Swift 3, there have been a few changes in the initialization. I used the migrator (which was great!) and everything compiles fine. But the app crashes when I try and retrieve attributes the Swift 2 way.

I have thoroughly researched this problem.

There are few examples of how to initialize NSFetchResultsController and NSFetchRequest, but the various responses on StackOverflow are competing or currently inadequate when explaining the retrieval. Apple's documentation, too, is clear but not working.

Here is my code where Person is the Entity:

```
// MARK: - Initialize Fetch Results

var fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<Person>()

    func setFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {

    do {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Giver.fetchRequest()

        let fetchResult = try moc?.fetch(fetchRequest)


        // CANNOT FIGURE OUT WHAT GOES HERE e.g.

        // person.name = fetchResult.first (this does not work)

        // person.name = fetchResults (this does not work)


        let sortDescriptor = SortDescriptor(key: "names", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    } catch {

        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }

    return setFetchRequest()
}

// MARK: - Retrieve Fetch Request

func getFetchRequest() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Giver> {

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: setFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

At the moment, there is no error, save the yellow triangle indicating that "fetchResult" has not been used. I am trying to fetch a few attributes: name: String, age: Int, photo: BinaryData. How would I retrieve these attributes?

I realize Swift 3 is still in beta. Just frustrated experiencing the pangs of source-breaking changes.

Comment: Two questions: (1) can you please add information about the crash? Like error messages, stack trace. (2) Why are you performing the fetch and then adding a sort descriptor only afterward?

Comment: Sure (1) **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, code=2, address=0x16fc8ffco** When I tap the tabBar icon, the app freezes and I get an lldb error. Problem looks like it's with the fetch. (2) I didn't know that the order mattered. It worked before in Swift 2.2

Comment: So, I tried _ = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest) within the do try catch statement. This was the response in the console: **warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
(lldb)**